# How to select rows from table that matches where clause on two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to select rows from table that matches where clause on two columns? I came up with below query. Please advice if there is better way with less text.

```
SELECT name, number 
FROM namenumber 
WHERE name IN (“Car”) AND number = “1234"
UNION 
SELECT name, number 
FROM namenumber 
WHERE name IN ("Train") AND number = "5678"
UNION 
SELECT name, number 
FROM namenumber 
WHERE name IN ("Flight") AND number = "9012";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, number FROM namenumber 
WHERE (name, number) IN ( 
    (“Car”,“1234"), ("Train", "5678"), ("Flight", "9012") 
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be just like this this

```
    SELECT name, number FROM namenumber 
         WHERE (name in (“Car”) and number = “1234") OR 
               (name in ("Train") and number = "5678") OR 
               (name in ("Flight") and number = "9012")
```

Comment: Should be simplified to name = 'Car' and ... etc.

Comment: Yes, it can be, though not sure why the question was posted like this, so provided answer accordingly